# Copy files from one folder to another but have an interval between each file

Tags: command-line, scripts, copy

Is there a way to copy files from folder a to folder b but have the process pause for a second between each file?
I want to copy a whole lot of files to a watch folder but I know from experience that if I copy all of them at once (either through terminal cp or GUI) it will make my rtorrent crash...
If i could copy the files with a second interval between them, that would give rtorrent the time to handle things. If I could do that from one command, that would save me from doing it one by one manually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Single command solutions

Among many options, including loops that make use of `cp` and `sleep`, we could opt for `find` with two `-exec` flags to run those exact commands.

```bsh
find ~/dir_1/ -type f -maxdepth 1  -exec cp {} ~/dir_2 \;  -exec sleep 1   \;
```

Here the options are:

- `~/dir_1` , the origin directory, through which `find` works.
- `-type f` get only files
- `-maxdepth 1` descend down 1 level maximum in the directory tree; prevents descending into subdirectories
- `-exec cp {} ~/dir_2 \;` copy the currently processed file designated by `{}` parameter to `~/dir_2`. The `\;` designates for `cp` to process single file at a time instead of tacking as many files as possible into `{}`. The backslash in `\;` is necessary to prevent shell from misinterpreting that as command terminator.
- `exec sleep 1 \;` executes `sleep 1` per each current file.

If you have a list of files in a file, you can do:

```bsh
xargs -I % --arg-file=input.txt sh -c 'cp % ~/dir_2/ ;sleep 1'
```

Options here are:

- `-I %` designates the symbol which refers to file within the command
- `--arg-file=input.txt` read arguments to command from specific file
- `sh -c 'cp % ~/dir_2/ ;sleep 1'` execute `/bin/sh` with provided commands by `-c '...'` flag; `%` will be substituted with filename.

#### Loop solutions

You could use a for loop for instance

```bsh
for f in "/path/to/folder_1"/*; do
    cp "$f"  "/path/to/folder_2/"
    sleep 1
done
```

For clarity, this is formatted on multiple lines, but this works as a single line just as well. You could also turn this into a function:

```bsh
delaycp(){
    for f in "$1"/*; do
        cp "$f"  "$2"/
        sleep 1
    done
}
```

And use it as

```bsh
delaycp "/path/to/folder1" "/path/to/folder2"
```

Alternatively, if you want to copy only certain files, not everyting that `*` glob captures in the directory, you could always make use of pathname expansion, something like `file{1..25}`, or have an input text file, something like this `input.txt`:

```bsh
/path/to/folder_1/file1
/path/to/folder_1/file2
/path/to/folder_1/file3
```

And from there make use of `while IFS= read -r line` structure to read the file:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    cp "$line" "/path/to/folder_2/${line##*/}"
    sleep 1
done < input.txt
```

Comment: What is the "or" clause in your `while` loop intended to do?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Extra protection for case when file doesn't end in `\n` newline.  Create this file as example: `printf "Line one\nLine two" > input.txt`. The while loop without that or clause will only get `Line one`. Why ? Because ` read` built in returns success only when line ends with `\n`. The `Line two` will still end up in the `line` variable, but `read` will return fail exit status. So that's why we need extra check in case the variable is nonempty.

Comment: In your explanation for the `find` solution, the first argument should be `~/dir_1` instead of `~/dir_2`. The whole command is correct, just the explanation isn't.

Answer (score 2):

#### With `parallel`

Here’s a [`parallel` [image: Install parallel]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/parallel) solution, give the arguments to `parallel` with `:::` exactly like with `cp` or use a file list:

```bsh
parallel -j1 'cp {} /path/to/dir2/;sleep 1' ::: /path/to/dir1/* # or
parallel -j1 'cp {} /path/to/dir2/;sleep 1' :::: /path/to/file_list.txt
```

The `-j` option tells `parallel` to run only `1` job at once rather than running jobs in parallel, the single quotes simply contain the script where `{}` is replaced with the currently processed file and `:::` or `::::` introduce the argument list or file(s) respectively. See `man parallel` for *much* more.

#### With `find -exec`

`find` provides a convenient way of running commands on the findings, e.g. to copy every `.log` file in and under the current directory do:

```bsh
find -name "*.log" -exec sh -c 'cp "$0" /path/to/dir2/;sleep 1' "{}" \;
```